# Early 2011 MacBook Pro does not standby correctly

Tags: macbook-pro, network, sleep-wake, afp, high-sierra

My Early 2011 15" MBP non-retina will not enter standby mode correctly. Meaning, when inactive for a few minutes, rather than just turning off the display, it goes into sleep mode, causing network shares to disconnect.

I have the Energy Saver settings set to never sleep while on power

This is a big problem for me, since I use NAS shares to store much of my work.

Is there a way to either
A) Disable sleep mode while plugged in (because usually when I need the shares up I'm plugged in) OR
B) Configure macOS to keep AFP shares connected while in sleep mode

I am running 10.13 High Sierra Beta

Comment: Well long story short I ended up reinstalling the OS from scratch for other issues - I will keep you updated as to whether or not the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

This [Support Page at Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202124) does not specify your MBP as fulfilling the hardware requirements for using Standby mode:

```
•   MacBook (2015 and later)
•   MacBook Pro (2012 and later)
•   MacBook Air (2010 and later)
•   SSD and Fusion drive versions of Mac mini (2012 and later)
•   SSD and Fusion drive versions of iMac (2012 and later)
•   Mac Pro (Late 2013)
```

Comment: Then why is my MBP going to full sleep mode when I have it set Never to Sleep?